# php code analysis

Tags: php

```
$test = 'aaaaaa';
$abc = & $test;
unset($test);
echo $abc;
```

It outputs 'aaaaaa',which is already unset,can you explain this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it unsets `$test`, but the value is not deleted because there is another reference to it, namely `$abc`.

Answer (score 1):

When you call:

```
$abc =& $test;
```

It points $abc at the same object in memory that $test is pointing at. It doesn't point $abc at $test - there's a subtle difference.

This means you can destroy $test, but $abc will still be pointing at the object in memory, so the value is not destroyed.